# how to tune postgres for IO waits

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, database-tuning

I have a java application writing and reading some data on postgress database. On running long duration test i see failures after a continues buildup of IO waits. Any suggestions to further dig down on what could be causing this IO buildup

[image]

Comment: Tune your statements so that they do less I/O, or get a stronger disk.

Comment: Check your queries, which queries cause most of the io?

Comment: It could be anything from get faster disks, to get more RAM to better cache data, to build an index to make your queries more efficient.  Using auto_explain to get the execution plans of the slowest queries is probably the best way to figure out if you can do the last of those.